# J2me starts confusion

Tags: mobile, java-me

I have knowledge of core Java and Android.  now I wish to learn J2ME.

What are the tools are needed for start with J2ME.
and  I read some tutorial for starting like  http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/java-platform-micro-edition.shtml In this tutorial I read that I need to download 
sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2_5_1-windows (WTK) along with java.
 But in Oracle site when I check for j2me section they are saying to download sun_java_me_sdk-3_0-win and start . so which is first point to start J2me. and what the diffrence in both of these two .Any good site link to refer will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to develop for real-world devices you will need to download the 2.5 version of the WTK, as there are only a few J2ME devices which support J2M2 3.0 (if any). You can download WTK 2.5 here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR

2.5 differs significantly from 3.0 and again: developing with 3.0 is of no use for existing devices.

Here's an overview of the feature of 2.5:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html

As fas as I can see, the tutorial you posted is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and useful response.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to read **j2me complete reference** ..as you know core java already it is very easy to learn J2ME...,J2ME SDK3 is just little different from J2ME WTK 2.5.2 ,

check the following url for learn more or start with Java Microedition :

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/mobile-development/threads/302854/646446#post646446

Answer (score 0):

To start developing you need a IDE ,is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development. I suggest you Netbeans, which you can download from here : [NetBeans IDE Download Bundles](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) and select a bundle which support Java ME(So you no longer need to download Java ME SDK,you'll get it along with Netbeans).

The next thing you need is to install the wireless toolkit as you read in the tutorial. Which you can get from :[Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) 
The toolkit includes the emulation environments, performance optimization and tuning features, documentation, and examples that developers need to bring efficient and successful wireless applications.

Now you are ready to start .

Here are some links that can help you to start with :

[Wireless Development Tutorial Part I](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/)

[J2ME Tutorial, Part 1: Creating MIDlets](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html)

[Guide to getting started in J2ME for the Motorola A780 phone](http://web.mit.edu/bentley/www/mobile/j2meguide/)

[Deploying Wireless Java Applications](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/deploy/)

Comment: Sanjay, Thanks for this quick and useful response.